# REST Service not working-Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I want to implement a Phill Sturgeon CodeIgniter RESTServer library in my project. 
 I copied the files **rest.php, Format.php, REST_Controler.php** in folders **config,library,library** respectively.

I created my controller called services with following code:

```
<?php
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class services extends REST_Controller {  

    function Teams_get(){

        $teamNames=$this->team_model->getTeamNames();

         $this->response($teamNames);
    }
```

TeamModel is autoloaded in my **autoload.php**. When I want to run Teams_get method in my browser result is:

`{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}`

I read [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205468/) that I should change **REST_Controler.php** configuration file, but this change should only be done if POST methods are not working.

My services should be public, so I don't need authentication methods.

What's wrong here?

Comment: What URL are you using to access your API?  You want to go to `/services/Teams`, not `/services/Teams_get`.  The `_get` (or `_post`) is added by the server depending on how you access the URL (`GET` vs `POST`).

Comment: That is an answer. Please, give it as answer so I can check it! Thank you man!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When calling your API, the URL should just be the name of the method, without the `_get` (or `_post`).  That is added by the REST server depending on how the URL is called (`GET` vs `POST`).

So, to call your `Teams_get` method, you want to send a `GET` request to the URL `/services/Teams` (not `/services/Teams_get`).

Docs: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests